# Authenticate jwt in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, jwt

This is my login code:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;
console.log(email, password);

try {
  if (email && password) {
  const accessToken = jwt.sign(email, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET)

      res.json(accessToken);
 } else res.sendStatus(400);
} catch (error) {
  res.sendStatus(500);
}
});
```

I want to use *accessToken* in my other file:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
socket.on('joinRoom', ({ username, room }) => {
 const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room, *accessToken*);

socket.join(user.room);
})
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do this, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a [middleware](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/) function:

```
//client side send token
const socket = io({
  auth: {
    token: "abc"
  }
});

//server side
io.use((socket, next) => {
  const token = socket.handshake.auth.token;
  // ...
});
```